# How to join multiple select statements in SQL and display in different colums

Tags: sql

I wrote a query that joins two tables that shows the total `no. of appointments` and `leads` using the `union` keyword and I would like the result of this query to be displayed in two different columns, I am having a tough description

```
SELECT COUNT(FilteredAppointment.createdbyname) AS Appointment
FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit 
INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser 
    ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid 
INNER JOIN FilteredAppointment 
    ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredAppointment.createdby
UNION
SELECT COUNT(FilteredLead.fullname) AS Lead
FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit 
INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser 
    ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid 
INNER JOIN FilteredLead 
    ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredLead.createdby
WHERE (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch))
```

My desired result is:

```
CRITERIA | Appointment | Leads
Total    | 200         | 123
```

Comment: Is the where clause inteded for both selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is not the correct approach.  Union combines or merges to result sets with the same number of columns and data types.  I would do something like this instead.

```
SELECT 
    (   SELECT COUNT(FilteredAppointment.createdbyname)
        FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit INNER JOIN
              FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid INNER JOIN
              FilteredAppointment ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredAppointment.createdby
        WHERE (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch))
    ) AS Appointment ,
    (   SELECT COUNT(FilteredLead.fullname)
        FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit INNER JOIN
              FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid INNER JOIN
              FilteredLead ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredLead.createdby
        WHERE (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch))
    ) AS Lead
```

In response to your comment to be able to compare the numbers to other branches, I would try something like this.

```
SELECT  FilteredBusinessUnit.name , 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FilteredAppointment.createdbyname IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Appointments,
        SUM(CASE WHEN FilteredAppointment.fullname IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Leads
FROM    FilteredBusinessUnit 
        INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredAppointment ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredAppointment.createdby
        LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredLead ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredLead.createdby
WHERE   (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch1, @Branch2)) 
GROUP BY FilteredBusinessUnit.name
```

The where clause can be left out if you want to look at all branches.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new with SQL, and I have another difficulty.
I would also like to compare the total no. of Leads and Appointment of two or more branches with this result.
CRITERIA | Appointment | Leads
Lagos    | 200         | 123

Comment: so you want to group by branch name?

Comment: I am not grouping by branch name, I am filtering by branch name, I would like to pick multiple branch in my filter and My result should display respective branches and their corresponding criteria(Appointment and leads)

Comment: I am not grouping by branch name, I am filtering by branch name, I would like to pick multiple branch in my filter and My result should display respective branches and their corresponding criteria(Appointment and leads)

Comment: I agree with Gordon below.  It really appears as though you are wanting to filter and group by branch.

Answer (score 0):

Do this with a `cross join` rather than `union`:

```
select 'Total', Appointment, Leads
from (SELECT COUNT(FilteredAppointment.createdbyname) AS Appointment
      FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit INNER JOIN
            FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid INNER JOIN
            FilteredAppointment ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredAppointment.createdby
     ) c1 cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(FilteredLead.fullname) AS Leads
      FROM  FilteredBusinessUnit INNER JOIN
            FilteredSystemUser ON FilteredBusinessUnit.businessunitid = FilteredSystemUser.businessunitid INNER JOIN
            FilteredLead ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredLead.createdby
      WHERE (FilteredBusinessUnit.name IN (@Branch))
     ) t
```

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new with SQL, and I have another difficulty.
I would also like to compare the total no. of Leads and Appointment of two or more branches with this result.
CRITERIA | Appointment | Leads
Lagos    | 200         | 123
Abuja    | 210         | 323
New York | 200         | 123

Comment: I am not grouping by branch name, I am filtering by branch name, I would like to pick multiple branch in my filter and My result should display respective branches and their corresponding criteria(Appointment and leads)

Comment: I am not grouping by branch name, I am filtering by branch name, I would like to pick multiple branch in my filter and My result should display respective branches and their corresponding criteria(Appointment and leads)

Comment: @Tope . . . If the solutions here don't answer your question, ask another question.  Focus on what the input data looks like and the results you want to see.